# Remove redundant delegate constructor call?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, resharper

I downloaded ReSharper and it is telling me to change this line:

```
dispMap.OnDraw += new EventHandler(dispMap_OnDraw);
```

To be this line:

```
dispMap.OnDraw += dispMap_OnDraw;
```

Because the first line is a "redundant delegate constructor call."

Is this true? In the automatically generated designer code for forms the syntax is based on the first piece of code and when typing in `dispMap.OnDraw +=` and hitting TAB the IDE automatically generates `new EventHandler(dispMap_OnDraw)`

I'm just curious about this one. Does ReSharper have a point?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. I have done this in several cases.

The delegate constructor call should be implicit; the type can be inferred from `OnDraw` and validated against the method signature of `dispMap_OnDraw`.

Also, a quote from [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163970.aspx) appears relevant:

> Because the += operator merely concatenates the internal invocation
>   list of one delegate to another, you can use the += to add an
>   anonymous method. Note that with anonymous event handling, you cannot
>   remove the event handling method using the -= operator unless the
>   anonymous method was added as a handler by first storing it to a
>   delegate and then registering that delegate with the event.

I believe the delegate instance is created either way, but since you don't have an object reference for the delegate when you implicitly instantiate, you can't remove it with the `-=` operator.

Answer (score 5):

It does have a point. The second line is shorthand for the first. Depending on your coding standards/conventions, you could use either one, but the first one does add a lot of noise.

Answer (score 3):

If you compare the IL generated in both cases, you'll see that they are the same. Here's both cases in C#, and the IL they result in.

Example C#:

```
namespace EventTest
{
    public class Publisher
    {
        public delegate void SomeEvent(object sender);
        public event SomeEvent OnSomeEvent;
        public event SomeEvent OnOtherEvent;
    }

    public class Subscriber
    {
        public Subscriber(Publisher p)
        {
            p.OnSomeEvent += new Publisher.SomeEvent(Respond);
            p.OnOtherEvent += Respond;
        }

        public void Respond(object sender)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here's the IL for the constructor. Pay attention to lines `IL_000a` through `IL_0028`.

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor(class EventTest.Publisher p) cil managed
{
  // Code size       48 (0x30)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  nop
  IL_0007:  nop
  IL_0008:  ldarg.1
  IL_0009:  ldarg.0
  IL_000a:  ldftn      instance void EventTest.Subscriber::Respond(object)
  IL_0010:  newobj     instance void EventTest.Publisher/SomeEvent::.ctor(object,
                                                                          native int)
  IL_0015:  callvirt   instance void EventTest.Publisher::add_OnSomeEvent(class EventTest.Publisher/SomeEvent)
  IL_001a:  nop
  IL_001b:  ldarg.1
  IL_001c:  ldarg.0
  IL_001d:  ldftn      instance void EventTest.Subscriber::Respond(object)
  IL_0023:  newobj     instance void EventTest.Publisher/SomeEvent::.ctor(object,
                                                                          native int)
  IL_0028:  callvirt   instance void EventTest.Publisher::add_OnOtherEvent(class EventTest.Publisher/SomeEvent)
  IL_002d:  nop
  IL_002e:  nop
  IL_002f:  ret
}
```

Conclusion: I don't see any reason to change your code, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

it works fine, I have DevExpress and it tells me the same!